# Why is the size of A equal to 8 and not 4?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

As far as I know, an array which is passed as a function argument isn't copied completely but is only a pointer to the address of the first element in the array. To see it in action I wrote a peace of code, which I found on the internet and expected the `sizeof(A)` in `SumOfElements()` should be 4. Somehow it is 8. What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int SumOfElements(int A[]) {
    int i, sum = 0;
    int size = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
    printf("SOE - size of A: %d, size of A[0]: %d\n", sizeof(A), sizeof(A[0]));
    for (i=0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += A[i];
    }
    return sum;

}

int main () {
    int A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int total = SumOfElements(A);
    printf("main - size of A: %d, size of A[0]: %d\n", sizeof(A), sizeof(A[0]));
    //printf("Sum of elements = %d\n", total);

}
```

Comment: Print the result of `sizeof` with `%zu`, not `%d`. What size are pointers in your C implementation? Why do you think they are four bytes rather than eight?

Comment: Well, when i print out the sum it also adds the first two numbers of the array, it gives back sum = 3 instead of sum = 1;

Comment: The sum of the first two elements of the array has nothing to do with the size of a pointer, any more than how much stuff is in a house has to do with how many digits are in the street number posted on the front door of the house.

Comment: the array has five elements and in the main function A has the size 20. So the pointer should have the size of 4, right?

Edit: Nevermind, i got it...